# How to make Constexpr function when "failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime"

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, c++17

I have `struct` that is specialised by an `enum Id`. I have a `idOf` function that takes a `Type<Id>` and returns the template-parameters.

I cannot really modify all the Types to include an extra member and recon this must be super simple to solve as `constexpr`.

I have hit an issue when the initialisation of the Type object is outside the same code module I get compilation errors for using my `constexpr` function (embedded as comment in code example). IN the example I use a `getA()` method returning reference to cause this however `idOf()` doesn't actually depend on the actual content of the structure and only its type.

Live code example: https://godbolt.org/z/8f649T64c

```
#include <cstdint>

enum Id { A, B, C };

template<Id cId>
struct Type;

template<> 
struct Type<A> { int t; };

template<Id cId>
constexpr Id idOf( const Type<cId>& = {} )
{ return cId; }

Type<A>& getA();

int main( int argc, char**)
{
    Type<A>& a = getA();

    /// ERROR: error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
    /// message: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
    /// message : see usage of 'data'
    constexpr Id id = idOf( a );

    return (int)id;
}
```

Help greatly appreciated :D

EDIT: The simplest workaround is ugly but break the connection to the object value that comes form outside the scope. This feels like a complete 'hack' but I put it here for reference:
`constexpr Id id = idOf( std::decay_t<decltype(a)>() )`
This essentially to resolves to `id = idOf( Type() ) which is fine as constexpr.

Comment: As a guess `idOf( Type<cId> = {} )`.  Not at a compiler, canpt check.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I thought the same and sadly doesn't solve it

Comment: Can you add a member *function*?

Comment: I'm asking as I would prefer not to as there are >80 structs to modify while the information i need is already known by the compiler. the `isOf` is compile time in all but the use of the 'parameter' for the type deduction so expect there is a means to reimplement `idOf` using another mechanism.... unless somebody can say ther is a language limitation here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution I have got is using a template object to determine the `Id` instead of using a `constexpr` expression:

```
template <typename cId> 
struct IdOf;

template <Id cId >
struct IdOf< Type<cId> > : std::integral_constant<Id, cId> {};

template<typename T>
constexpr Id idOf = IdOf< std::decay_t<T> >::value;
```

This changes the caller site to:

```
constexpr Id id = idOf<decltype(a)>;
```

Its not bad but still feels like a 'workaround' to me unless this issue identifies an actual limitation of `constexpr`

Live compiling code here: https://godbolt.org/z/s5bTTdqW9

EDIT: Added `idOf<>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your reference.  You are not allowed to use a reference inside a constant expression unless:

> an id-expression referring to a variable or a data member of reference type, unless the reference is usable in constant expressions (see below) or its lifetime began within the evaluation of this expression

If you changed it from a reference to a value, no problem.

---

```
template<Id cId>
constexpr std::integral_constant<Id, cId> idOf( const Type<cId>& = {} )
{ return {}; }
```

here I encode the return value in the type.

```
constexpr Id id = decltype(idOf( a ))::value;
```

and here I extract it.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/eafqPf9MT).

An alternative approach using tags:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t {using type=T;};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<std::decay_t<T>> dtag{};
```

then we add:

```
template<Id cId>
constexpr std::integral_constant<Id, cId> idOf( tag_t<Type<cId>> = {} )
{ return {}; }
```

and we can do this:

```
constexpr Id id2 = idOf(dtag<decltype( a )>);
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/14jMsvPKh).

---

Off topic:

`tag_t` is useful in that it lets you pass types around as values.  So I can pass a type into a lambda without template lambda support, or store a variant of types (not values of that type, but types).

So it isn't a one-off type, but something useful elsewhere.  For example:

```
template<class...Ts>
using types = std::variant<tag_t<Ts>...>;
template<class...Ts>
constexpr types<Ts...> get_type( std::variant<Ts...> const& v ) {
  constexpr types<Ts...> table[] = {
    tag<Ts>...
  };
  if (v.valueless_by_exception())
    throw std::bad_variant_access{};
  return table[v.index()];
}
```

here I just made an enumeration of the types on a `variant` that can be converted back to the type itself using `std::visit`.

Comment: Some value here but it is adding complexity to both the function an call-site.
The same effect is achieved by just modifying the caller site with the original function and using:
`idOf( std::decay_t<decltype(a)>() );`

Comment: @Crog That presumes the `Type<A>` are all trivial, or there could be side effects.

Comment: Yes, I don' like the workaround, if it were not trival the workaround could use `std::declval` but thats pushing even more 'ugly' to the client code... simplicity is always the trickiest thing to achieve!
EDIT: I don't think declval has constexpr... my situation is luckily trivial by design